# react-native-iap purchaseUpdatedListener with Android auto-renew subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I'm currently implementing in-app purchase with React Native via react-native-iap

When I use purchaseUpdatedListener to listen to subscription renew in iOS, it works normally. However, I can only listen to the first subscription purchase in Android, subsequent renewals are not listened.

Is there anyway I can do it with react-native-iap in Android?

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button} from 'react-native'
import {
  finishTransaction,
  getSubscriptions,
  purchaseErrorListener,
  purchaseUpdatedListener,
  requestSubscription,
} from 'react-native-iap';

const SubscribeScreen = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let iapUpdatedListener, iapErrorListener;

    initConnection().then(() => {
      iapUpdatedListener = purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase) => {
        console.log('Ding ding: ', purchase);
        finishTransaction({
          purchase,
        });
      });

      iapErrorListener = purchaseErrorListener((error) => {
        console.log('iap error: ', error);
      });
    })

    return () => {
      iapUpdatedListener?.remove();
      iapErrorListener?.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const onBuySubscription = async () => {
    const subs = await getSubscriptions({
      skus: [<SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID>]
    })

    const { productId, subscriptionOfferDetails } = subs[0]
    const firstOffer = subscriptionOfferDetails[0];
    const { offerToken } = firstOffer;

    await requestSubscription({
      sku: productId,
      ...(offerToken && {
        subscriptionOffers: [
          {
            sku: productId,
            offerToken,
          },
        ],
      }),
    });
  }

  return (
    <Button
      title="Purchase subscription"
      onPress={onBuySubscription}
    />
  )
}
```